# minus counter number by 1 every time the user clicks refresh and when it gets to 1 reset back to 7 - javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, click, refresh

I have a counter snippet and right now it's set so it counts down from 7 every 1000 ms's but what i want it to do is

1. not animate
2. when the user clicks refresh it goes down by one, so it's static.

here is part of the code that i have at the moment and the rest is in it's core javascript file which it gets some of it's syntax from.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myCounter = null
    var timerId = null

    function loadCounter() {
        myCounter = new Counter("my_counter",{
            digitsNumber: 2,
            direction: Counter.ScrollDirection.Upwards,
            characterSet: Counter.DefaultCharacterSets.numericUp,
            charsImageUrl: "_images/numeric_up_blackbg5.png",
            markerImageUrl: "_images/marker.png"
        });

        myCounter.value = 7;

        timerId = window.setInterval("myCounter.setValue(parseInt(myCounter.value) - 1, 450);", 1000); 
    }

    loadCounter();
</script>
```

I'm pretty inexperienced at javascript so if you could be thorough that would be fantastic. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the page from refreshing, or store the counter value from page-to-page. As far as I know, browsers will not let you prevent them from refreshing the page, but will only let you prompt them asking if they would like to refresh.

Comment: Thanks kingcoyote for the reply. yes i want to store a counter value from page-to-page.

Comment: A variable won't survive a page refresh. You'll have to use a cookie.

Comment: what if the variable is stored in a .txt file on the webhost somehow?

Comment: BUMP. i have to stop working on this at 2:30 (Melbourne, Australian times) and i'm only half done. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested your javascript variables will be cleared each time the page is refreshed. So you cannot store the counter in a JS variable.

You have two options

1) if you using a severside technology such as PHP, ASP etc you could store it in a text file.

2) use a cookie. This is probably the easiest approach.

So the first time the user visist the page check if a cookie exist. If it does then you can incremember the counter in it and check if it equals 7.

If it does not exist create one you probably want to use a Session Cookie so that it expires once t he user closes their browser assuming you do not want to keep a counter if a user visited the page one week ago and comes back again today.  See here for some information about how to read and write session cookies http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/cookie.shtml

Comment: Okay, would you be able to give me a code example of the session cookie to work with my situation and code. Thank you.

Comment: @happycamper1221 did you not even bother following his link? There are code samples there.

Comment: I did. but i only started web development about 4 weeks ago and mainly know html and css not javascript. can't somebody give me a code example that works with my situation - i don't know javascript.

Comment: your going to have to learn it sooner or later may as well be now